# Cache files isn't storing for all stages in GitLab CI

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have gitlab-ci script for building and running tests. But, directories that were created in build process are deleted. 
My script:

```
stages:
  - build
  - test

server:
  stage: build
  script:
  - cd Server/NodeJS
  - npm install
  - npm install zmq
  cache:
    key: "$CI_BUILD_NAME"
    untracked: true
    paths:
    - Server/NodeJS/node_modules/

client:
  stage: build
  script:
  - cd Client/web
  - npm install
  - npm run build-demo
  - npm run build-main
  cache:
    key: "$CI_BUILD_NAME"
    untracked: true
    paths:
    - Client/web/build-main/

functional_tests:
  stage: test
  script:
  - cd Server/NodeJS
  - ls node_modules/
  - ls ../../Client/web/
  ...
```

ls doesn't print caches directories. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should rather use artifacts than cache for your use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you haven't defined a global cache, neither a cache in the `functional_tests` job, it doesn't know there is any.

You need to do something like this:

```
functional_tests:
  stage: test
  script:
  - cd Server/NodeJS
  - ls node_modules/
  - ls ../../Client/web/
  cache:
    key: "$CI_BUILD_NAME"
    untracked: true
    paths:
    - Client/web/build-main/
    - Server/NodeJS/node_modules/
```

Also, please note that **the cache is provided on a best-effort basis, so don't expect that the cache will be always present.**

Therefore you cannot assume there will always be the cache, you need to write the script as there isn't.